# How to convert a vector to a list?

Tags: python, list

If I have a vector:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I convert it to:

```
b = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: What is a vector? And what have you tried?

Comment: On my machine, `type([1, 2, 3])` shows `<class 'list'>`, so you don't have to do anything - it's already a list :-)

Comment: Your "vector" is a list. What you want is to convert a list of integers into a list of strings.

Comment: `b = list(map(str, a))`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [str(i) for i in a]
```

Comment: Alternative way: `map(str, b)`.

Comment: @Delgan Only in Py2 ... `list` call needed in Py3